# how to relate a user with a session in symfony

Tags: session, symfony

I have a symfony app with a User entity. When a user authenticate, it has a session (normal session mechanism) entry and a user entry.

I have a web service which access the symfony app and pass an argument to it (the username for example).
What I want is that symfony only do something if the user is still connected (ie, his session is not expired).

How can I know what is the session_id associated with that user?
Would it be a good idea to extend the session to have an aditional field like a user_id and then have an associate entity which can do requests on the session (my sessions are stored in mysql table) to retrieve the session associated with the user?

Comment: new to symfony and wondering the same thing.. im thinking the AppKernel would check if theres an active session and if so, continue the request and if not, return a 404

Comment: Read on authentication and user providers in the official docs.

Comment: thanks to point out that, it's interesting.